# What's the difference between "pip install bs4" and "pip install BeautifulSoup4"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I search about the installation of the BeautifulSoup lib, sometimes I see `pip install bs4`, and sometimes `pip install BeautifulSoup4`.

What's the difference between these 2 methods of installation?

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bs4` is technically a different package; however, it is a dummy package designed to install the correct package: `beautifulsoup4`.

https://pypi.org/project/bs4/

TLDR: You can use either the short name or long name

Comment: thanks man, I totally forgot to see the pypi.org/project/ lol